# Erroneous tree type:, linked list

Tags: java, exception, data-structures, linked-list

im trying to create a linked list but i keep getting that error, i am new to linked list and cant figure out whats happening. the code seems to work other lists that insert two data types into the node class.
EDIT: i am using netbeans and all 3 classes are in the same package, and they are the only

main class

```
 public class assignment6 {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PQueue p = new PQueue();
            p.push(22);
            p.push(11);
            p.push(2);
            p.display();
            /*

            */

        }

 }
```

linked list class

```
    class PQueue {

        public Node firstL;

        PQueue(){
            firstL = null;    
        }

        public boolean isEmpty(){
            return (firstL == null);
        }

        public void push(int num){
            Node n = new Node(num);

            n.next = firstL;
            firstL = n;
        }

        public void display(){
            Node link = firstL;
            while(link != null){
                link.display();
                link=link.next;

            }
        }
    }
```

node class

```
    public class Node {
        public int num; 
        public Node next;

        public Node(int num){
            this.num = num;
        }

        public void display(){
            System.out.println(num);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I can't replicate your exception, are you perhaps importing the wrong `Node` class?

Comment: i am using netbeans all those classes are in the same package

Comment: never mind sorry i figured it out